# Chart.js - Shift/Stagger labels horizontally (for x axis) instead of rotating

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I don't want to rotate the labels of the x axis, so I disabled that behavior by setting `maxRotation: 0`. Of course, the labels overlap if I scale the chart:

[image: Correct layout]

[image: Overlapping labels]

I would like the labels to behave like this:

[image: Mockup: alternating labels]

Is that possible with standard chart.js options? Or is there another way to achieve that?

**EDIT**: Here is a codepen which shows the behaviour: https://codepen.io/JohnArcher/pen/wmeEMV

Comment: Can you make a codepen/fiddle code snippet of your code?

Comment: @VicJordan Sure. I added an example in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using autoSkip option on x axes ticks.

```
xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true
        }
}]}
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/

> A built-in label auto-skip feature detects would-be overlapping ticks and labels and removes every nth label to keep things displaying normally.

If that doesn't resolve your problem try use maxRotation, minRotation.

```
xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 90
        }
}]}
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already used 'autoSkip' but this is not want I want. I want to see all labels. max-/minRotation is also a good trick but for several reasons I can't use it. A staggering behaviour like described with suit the requirements best.